# Reverse Proxy with Apache and several physical servers

Tags: linux, networking, apache-http-server, reverse-proxy

I am sure that this question is  not a hard one for most of you. I have been struggling with it for the past two weeks. I am ready  to give up.

The situation is the following:
I have three different Raspberry Pi's in my network. Each one is running a different application that I want to be able to reach via a domain name.
The IP Addresses in the network are of the schema `192.168.178.x`

**Pi One is running Apache as a reverse Proxy as well as docker and bitwarden `(IP: 98)`**

**Pi Two is running home assistant as HassOs `(IP: 99)`**

**Pi Three is running nextcloud as a snap service `(IP: 100)`**

On Pi One I have in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` a configuration for each service. The bitwarden one is working and looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName bw.domain.com
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ProxyPass /.well-known !
 ProxyPass / http://localhost:8082/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8082/
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =bw.domain.com
 RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Keep in mind, this service is also running on Pi One. Ideally the redirect to HTTPS would happen in a file obove this but my imcompentence with apache has not allowed for such neatness.
The second service I want to reach is the nextcloud. I have configured it on a different Pi. The routing configuration on the Pi One looks like this (one of many non working versions):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName cloud.domain.com
 ProxyRequests Off
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =cloud.domain.com
 RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
 RewriteRule ^ http://192.168.178.100:80/ [proxy,last]
 ProxyPass / http://192.168.178.100:80/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.178.100:80/
 <Proxy http://192.168.178.100:80>

  Require all granted

  Options none

  ProxySet enablereuse=on

 </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am sure there is a ton of issues with this one. It has been Frankensteined together out of a bunch of tutorials.
What happens however is, that even though I have an SSL certificate active for this service, I get a warning in the browser before I can open the page. Then, it just opens up bitwarden but under the domain of `cloud.domain.com`. I am unable to reach Pi Three via the domain it has been assinged and thus also when I am outside my network. Granted these days that does not happen often but still that would be a desirable situation.

Can someone please tell me what to do here? I cannot say what the issue is anymore. I can provide logging information if so desired and all other things that could be relevant. I really want to understand what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for your consideration!

Comment: SSL certificate? But your VirtualHost is for port *:80 (the non-SSL HTTP port) and has no SSL options whatsoever.

Comment: You could start by having a look at the Apache error log and remove the syntax errors.  "https;//..."  Seriously?

Comment: It does work with the bitwarden installation @user1686. So I get correctly routed to https. Used to work with the other services as well as long as I had them on the same machine. 
GerardH.Pille I replaced the admittedly stupid mistake but have not gotten a change. The error log does not show anything and also did not show this error. Not sure how that is helping to resolve the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody comes across this and is as confused as I was/am, this is what got the cloud and bitwarden working. Home Assistant I still cannot access. I will update this once I figure it out, in case I ever do.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.178.98:80>
 ServerName cloud.domain.com
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass / http://192.168.178.100:80/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.178.100:80/

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =cloud.domain.com
 RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

The reroutet traffic from HTTPS goes to Port 443 and gets caught by the letsencrypt configured Virtual Host that looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName cloud.domain.com
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ProxyPass /.well-known !
 ProxyPass / http://192.168.178.100:80/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.178.100:80/
 RewriteEngine on
# Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
# because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

#  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =bw.domain.com
#  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bw.domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bw.domain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I can see that there is issues with that but it got it working for me. So maybe that helps someone.